# How to convert Ansible-Playbooks to be used with Ansible-API

Tags: python, ansible

I'm using Ansible to set up servers.
Sometimes I'm using the command `ansible-playbook <my-playbook.yml -i <inventory.txt>` and sometimes I'm using the Ansible Python API (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_api.html)

Unfortunatley I don't know how to insert my already existing playbooks in the API.

Here is the API:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import shutil
from ansible.module_utils.common.collections import ImmutableDict
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.playbook.play import Play
from ansible.executor.task_queue_manager import TaskQueueManager
from ansible.plugins.callback import CallbackBase
from ansible import context
import ansible.constants as C

class ResultCallback(CallbackBase):
    """A sample callback plugin used for performing an action as results come in

    If you want to collect all results into a single object for processing at
    the end of the execution, look into utilizing the ``json`` callback plugin
    or writing your own custom callback plugin
    """
    def v2_runner_on_ok(self, result, **kwargs):
        """Print a json representation of the result

        This method could store the result in an instance attribute for retrieval later
        """
        host = result._host
        print(json.dumps({host.name: result._result}, indent=4))

# since the API is constructed for CLI it expects certain options to always be set in the context object
context.CLIARGS = ImmutableDict(connection='local', module_path=['/to/mymodules'], forks=10, become=None,
                                become_method=None, become_user=None, check=False, diff=False)

# initialize needed objects
loader = DataLoader() # Takes care of finding and reading yaml, json and ini files
passwords = dict(vault_pass='secret')

# Instantiate our ResultCallback for handling results as they come in. Ansible expects this to be one of its main display outlets
results_callback = ResultCallback()

# create inventory, use path to host config file as source or hosts in a comma separated string
inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources='localhost,')

# variable manager takes care of merging all the different sources to give you a unified view of variables available in each context
variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)

# create data structure that represents our play, including tasks, this is basically what our YAML loader does internally.
play_source =  dict(
        name = "Ansible Play",
        hosts = 'localhost',
        gather_facts = 'no',
        tasks = [
            dict(action=dict(module='shell', args='ls'), register='shell_out'),
            dict(action=dict(module='debug', args=dict(msg='{{shell_out.stdout}}')))
         ]
    )

# Create play object, playbook objects use .load instead of init or new methods,
# this will also automatically create the task objects from the info provided in play_source
play = Play().load(play_source, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader)

# Run it - instantiate task queue manager, which takes care of forking and setting up all objects to iterate over host list and tasks
tqm = None
try:
    tqm = TaskQueueManager(
              inventory=inventory,
              variable_manager=variable_manager,
              loader=loader,
              passwords=passwords,
              stdout_callback=results_callback,  # Use our custom callback instead of the ``default`` callback plugin, which prints to stdout
          )
    result = tqm.run(play) # most interesting data for a play is actually sent to the callback's methods
finally:
    # we always need to cleanup child procs and the structures we use to communicate with them
    if tqm is not None:
        tqm.cleanup()

    # Remove ansible tmpdir
    shutil.rmtree(C.DEFAULT_LOCAL_TMP, True)
```

I already tried to convert the playbooks from yaml to python dictionary using

```py
import yaml
with open('ansible-files/main.yml') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f)
```

and then passing `data` in as `play_source`.

This will work for simple playbooks, but not for more complex ones, where different roles are involved. Is there a way to pass an existing playbook with roles, templates and other stuff directly to the API?

If not: Is there another way of using existing playbooks, when using the Python API without the need to rewrite everything by hand?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using PlaybookExecutor to execute the playbook which includes complex roles.

```
        executor = PlaybookExecutor(
            playbooks=[playbooks],
            inventory=self.inventory,
            variable_manager=self.variable_manager,
            loader=self.loader,
            passwords=self.passwords
        )
        executor.run()
```

The playbooks is yml file path.